# Need help correcting a Regex pattern I did

Tags: regex

I wanted to extract specific data from a data string.

This is the data string

```
** Case Description:
- Xyz Xyz
```

This is the regex pattern I used

```
Case Description:\n(.+)
```

This is the output I am getting

```
- help with the paperwork
```

How can I cancel out the "-"

Comment: Depending on where/how you use the regex, this could work just fine. What app are you working with?

Comment: Hey, I am using Integromat, I tested it there again and it worked, only one problem.

"-" that character comes with the output, what can I do to remove that

Comment: Maybe use `Case Description:\s+-\s*(.+)` in that case.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.
If it isn't too much, Could you tell me what exactly you did, it would help me better understand regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Case Description:\n\s*-\s*(.+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V9X5d2/1).

I'd recommend to use a more regex-friendly terminology since regex does not "cancel out" anything, regex either matches or does not match a piece of or the whole text.

In your case, you are matching `Case description:`, then a newline (line feed) char, and *capture* into Group 1 any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible. That means, you *captured* the hyphen and spaces that the line starts with.

Thus, what you need is *match* (consume) the hyphen and spaces without *capturing* them, that is what the suggested pattern does.